# Issues with DrawString on a Bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I have this constructor that takes in an input of an array of `Color` objects and some misc strings (like `file` location and size of `list`), and stores this heatmap into a `bitmap` instance called `_image_`. Everything works out fine, but my main issue is I have no way to render text onto this heatmap. I would like to overlay title text and x and y-axis labels onto this bitmap.

```
    public HeatMap(IEnumerable<Color> colors, int width, int height, string file, int U, int V) {
        if (colors == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("colors");
        if (width <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("width must be at least 1");
        if (height <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("height must be at least 1");

        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _file = file;
        _image = new Bitmap(U, V, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_image);

        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.Dispose();

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        foreach (Color color in colors) {
            _image.SetPixel(x, y, color); // This can be speeded up by using GH_MemoryBitmap if you want.
            y++;
            if (y >= V) {
                y = 0;
                x++;
            }
            if (x >= U)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Below, I also have a method that resizes the image (without too much distortion), and I figured I might as well make use of this since I have a `graphics` object I can use, like so:

```
private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, 0, 0, width, height);
        g.DrawString("A heatmap.", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using the above, I was able to overlay text over it, as a starting point. My question is, how do I add a white boarder over the above image (so my text doesn't overlap my graph), and then overlay x and y-axis text onto it?

I guess my specific question really is - how do I render text onto, say, every four columns of my heatmap? In most instances, there are 100 x-axis objects, and like 24 y-axis objects. The y-axis would have the time of the day, while the x-axis has the day of the year. My familiarity with using graphics in C# is very low, so any pointers is very appreciated.

Comment: This is not a great snippet, it doesn't actually have a DrawString() call nor a variable named `g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use the DrawString before the graphics.Dispose() and after the Clear().

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_image);
graphics.Clear(Color.WhiteSmoke);
graphics.DrawString("your text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
graphics.Dispose();
```

Where the PointF(0, 0) represents the up-left corner of your text placeholder, you've to calculate the text position based on the positions of your heatmap.

**UPDATE (alignment)**

You can align your text in relation with a virtual rectangle, doing something like:

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_image);
graphics.Clear(Color.WhiteSmoke);
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
graphics.DrawString("your text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100), stringFormat);
graphics.Dispose();
```

In this case I've created a virtual box of 100x100 positioned on the top-left corner, and the text is h/v centered relatively to this box.

Comment: Any ideas how to use `graphics.DrawString("Title Text", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, image.Width / 2, 20);` to display the text at the absolutely center? Currently, the title text is rendered at the first letter, as opposed to the center of the entire string.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input and help.